# Update SQL query multiple fields to update

Tags: sql, sql-update

Trying to update my tables by an update query, please see below the query, not sure if its the and that is giving me the issue?

```
update tb1 set class='X' and SUB_CLASSIFICATION='XX' where id=12345 and 
loc='0250' and TYPE='I' and CLASSIFICATION='B10'
```

Comment: Three simultaneous answers: change the first `AND` to a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Use comma `,` instead of `AND` in the `SET`

```
update tb1 set class='X', SUB_CLASSIFICATION='XX' where id=12345 and 
loc='0250' and TYPE='I' and CLASSIFICATION='B10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a '`,`' for updating multiple `columns`

```
update tb1 set class='X',SUB_CLASSIFICATION='XX' where id=12345 and 
loc='0250' and TYPE='I' and CLASSIFICATION='B10'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update tb1 
set class='X', SUB_CLASSIFICATION='XX' 
where id=12345 and loc='0250' and TYPE='I' and CLASSIFICATION='B10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your first AND should be a comma (,) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In set part ypu must use ',' - not AND

```
update tb1 set class='X', SUB_CLASSIFICATION='XX' where id=12345 and 
loc='0250' and TYPE='I' and CLASSIFICATION='B10'
```

Answer (score 0):

update tb1 set class='X', SUB_CLASSIFICATION='XX' 
where id=12345 and loc='0250' and TYPE='I' and CLASSIFICATION='B10'